# submitting form to forumspree.io doesn't work after the first email

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

As the title say, I can't receive the submitted messages from my website after I confirmed my email in the first submit.
I don't know if it's a problem of mine or theirs. I'm not using the default form they're showing in the website but this script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#contact_form').on("submit",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://formspree.io/mymail@gmail.com',
      data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $('#success_send').fadeIn(500);
        $('#success_send').delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
        $('#contact_form').find("input[type=text], textarea, input[type=email]").val("");
      },
      error: function(){
        $('#error_send').fadeIn(500);
        $('#error_send').delay(10000).fadeOut(500);
      }
    });
  });

});
```

I think should work, but as I said I get just the confirmation mail along with the first test message I sent to me and that's it.
Any clue of what's wrong?

Comment: Please describe more what "doesn't work" means.  Do you see the following attempts making the ajax request at all?  If so, did you confirm that the correct data is being sent on the requests?  What response code are they getting back?

Comment: The POST is a success, and my script indeed display the Success message in my webpage. But I don't get any email even after days.

Comment: And the email is expected to come from formspree.io?

Comment: I think so. I think they get my POST and use their server to send me the email since my website is static

Comment: In that case the issue appears to be on their side.  I would suggest reaching out to them directly and asking for support.

Comment: All right. I wanted be sure my code is correct. I already tried to contacting them via email but didn't get any answer. Do you know if there's an alternative service to formspree? Or anyway an alternative way to send an email from a form without php

Comment: I'm not familiar with email services offered on the web, however it's also off topic for StackOverflow questions to ask about off site resources, services, tutorials, etc, so this isn't the best place to ask about those things.

Comment: all right sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formspree.io still doesn't work so I solved the problem by changing service and using formcarry.com